# How can I reformat a "matrix report" in Google Sheets into a clean data sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Sorry for the imprecise title, I'm not sure what this format is called. I received a "research database" in format you see below and need to convert it (and dozens more like it) into a useable format.

The sheets look like this:

| COMPANY | Report 1 | Report 2 | Report 3 | Report 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 | 46.8 | -0.2 |  | 0.2 |
| Company 2 | 45.7 |  | -0.3 |  |

I need to convert it to a properly formatted data sheet so I can upload it to a database. In other words, it needs to become:

| Company | Report | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 | Report 1 | 46.8 |
| Company 1 | Report 2 | -0.2 |
| Company 1 | Report 3 |  |
| Company 2 | Report 4 | 0.2 |
| Company 2 | Report 1 | 45.7 |
| Company 2 | Report 3 | -0.3 |
| Company 2 | Report 4 |  |

It's ok if we end up with rows with no value, those are easy enough to purge.

[Sample sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hqAWXf6VEGXQmC0J8brzokWKOZrqVfgRhQBFHNe6WU4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to delete what appears to be test data from A9:C of your "Data as Is" sheet.

After that, delete everything you currently have in the results sheet (or create a new blank one) and place the following formula in A1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Company","Report","Score";SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF('Data as Is'!B2:E="",,'Data as Is'!A2:A&"~"&'Data as Is'!B1:E1&"~"&'Data as Is'!B2:E)),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null"),"~")})`

This will produce your headers and all results, with no-result rows already removed.

From there, you can format headers and data as you like.

Comment: Brilliant! This is perfect!

Comment: Glad it suited your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, where tab is your data

```
=query({
arrayformula(vlookup((roundup(flatten(sequence(columns(tab),rows(tab),1,1)/columns(tab)))),{flatten(sequence(columns(tab),rows(tab),1,1)),flatten(transpose(tab))},2,0)),
arrayformula(vlookup(mod(flatten(sequence(rows(tab),columns(tab),0,1)),columns(tab))+1,{flatten(sequence(rows(tab),columns(tab),1,1)),flatten(tab)},2,0)),
flatten(tab)
},"select * where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null and Col3 is not null",0)
```